# Script which takes details from file & runs command

Tags: shell-script, scripting

It would be helpful to understand how can I connect the second column in the script. currently using the below for loop

```
for i in cat server
do     
    echo ===$i====
    ssh -q $i 'netstat -tulpun | egrep '22|13''
done
```

multiple server with different port for example below are the server in the first column & port in the second

```
Jan 113  
Feb 114  
Mar 115  
Apr 116  
May 117
```

Comment: The highlighting of this question should give you a clue that you have only 3 single quotes in your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat server | while read str 
do
  server=$(echo "$str" | cut -d' ' -f 1)
  port=$(echo "$str" | cut -d' ' -f 2)
  echo server: "$server" port: "$port"
  ssh -q "$server" 'netstat | grep -E "'"$port"'"'
done
```

assuming the file with server-port pairs is called `server` and then extend that with your `ssh` command.

The `cat server` just assigns these two values to `i` in your for loop, you could do `for i in $(cat server)` but that doesn't give you the lines as the example above does and it is IMO easier to split the values on a line than to combine multiple values in consecutive (`for`) loop passages.

Comment: there is no command for login & netstat

Comment: @AngRed But you can figure out where to add those commands, can't you?

Comment: @AngRed there is no login in your script either, just fill in the two variables where you want them. You should always make sure your loops work before you try to do something more complex, especially if you are guessing how things work.

Comment: Its not working, the command should look likethis
ssh -q "$host" 'netstat -tulpun | egrep "$port"'

Comment: Of course that is not working your passing `egrep` the literal string `"$port"` which doesn't get expanded because it is between single quotes. `''` and the variable is called `$server` not `$host`

Comment: @AngRed I updated the answer. Please notice that use of  `egrep` is deprecated (see the man page).

Comment: Need one more help before every server it should do echo $server
because the output is getting merged of all the servers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `for i in $(cat server) ...`, consider using `while read` loop:

```
while read host port
do
    echo ===$host====
    ssh -q "$host" 'netstat -tulpun | egrep "'"$port"'"'
done < server
```

Assuming:

- there are exactly two whitespace-separated entries in each line,
- the second entry is a valid port number

Comment: shall i remove the bracket from for i in $(cat server)

Comment: @AngRed that was how your command should have looked. `for i in cat server` only loops over the words `cat` and `server`, not the output of `cat server`.

Comment: just to clarify that the command should look like this
ssh -q $host 'netstat -tulpun | grep $port"'

Comment: So the port is not for connecting? Then see the update.

Comment: for i in $(cat demo)
while read host port
do
    echo ===$host====
ssh -q "$server" 'netstat -tulpun | grep "$port"'
done
still not working

Comment: Did you see the update?

Comment: still not running, please have a check

./script_re: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
./script_re: line 3: `while read host port'

Comment: I was trying to do something else with that, I got it as I wanted.